# Automatic "simplification" can make an expression strictly more complex

Tags: simplifying-expressions, implementation-details

Mathematica's automatic simplification rules result in the following behavior:

```
-(a + b) x
(* (-a - b) x *)
```

On the other hand,

```
Simplify[-(a + b) x]
(* -(a + b) x *)

Simplify[(-a - b) x]
(* -(a + b) x *)
```

seems to imply that Mathematica considers the expression `-(a + b) x` to be simpler than `(-a - b) x`. Indeed,

```
LeafCount[(-a - b) x]
(* 9 *)

LeafCount[Simplify[-(a + b) x]]
(* 6 *)
```

(note that you need to keep the `Simplify` inside the latter expression, or else Mathematica will automatically convert the inner `-(a + b) x` to `(-a - b) x` and return `9`!)

This leads to the following very strange behavior:

```
list = {Simplify[-(a + b) x]}
(* {-(a + b) x} *)

list[[1]]
(* -(a + b) x *)

list[[1]] == -(a + b) x
(* -(a + b) x == (-a - b) x *)

MemberQ[list, -(a + b) x]
(* False *)

MemberQ[list, Evaluate[-(a + b) x]]
(* False *)
```

I can't think of any other Mathematica command where

```
[command] == [command output]
```

does not evaluate to `True` (or even more problematically, where

```
MemberQ[list, [output of running "list[[1]]"]]
```

evaluates to `False`, which is clearly incorrect). I feel like this is right on the borderline between "extremely counterintutive behavior" and a bug. (It just tripped me up hard in a real application.) Should I report it to Wolfram?

Comment: Are you aware that an expression that is printed as `- (a+b) x` may have multiple *different* internal representation?  This can be revealed with `FullForm` (try it on all your results).

Comment: @m_goldberg Is that formatting really preferred on this site? In my opinion, it makes my question tremendously more difficult to read.

Comment: @Szabolcs Running `FullForm` on every expression in this question that is printed as `-(a + b) x` always returns the same result `Times[-1, Plus[a, b], x]`.

Comment: Yes, it is one of the preferred forms. Another is to wrap output in comment delimiters `(* ,,, *)`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm going to edit the OP into that form. No offense, but the current format just looks awful to me.

Comment: That is not correct, but I see how my comment was misleading. When you enter `-(a+b) x`, it is `Times[Times[-1, Plus[a, b]], x]`, as you can check with `FullForm@Hold[-(a + b) x]`. What you get back from `Simplify` is `Times[-1, Plus[a, b], x]`. This explains why the first thing auto-evaluates but `Simplify`'s output does not.

Comment: @tparker The point of using `(* ... *)` instead of `>> ...` is to make the expression easy to evaluate after copying and pasting. With `>>` I need to edit that part out.  This matters more when you have a longer sequence of inputs/outputs in a single code block (otherwise each input needs to be copied separately anyway).  [This tool](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/12) automates this formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing two different operations: *Evaluation* and *Simplification*.  Every expression evaluates, possibly to itself.  This doesn't automatically make it simpler.  Indeed, some functions (e.g., `Expand`) have the express purpose of making expressions less simple as defined by `LeafCount` or associated measures used by `Simplify`.  Some types of evaluation produce output that is 100% equivalent to input (e.g, `a+a -> 2a`.  Others (e.g., `x/x -> 1`) do not.  This explained in, e.g., [tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html), and is basically because the system would be unusable for an actual computation if every singular case were considered.

In this particular case, you are further confused because you think that that `-(a+b)x` you type in is the same as the `-(a+b)x` that is output by `Simplify`.  This is not the case:

```
{Simplify[-(a+b) x],Hold[-(a+b) x]} // FullForm
(*List[Times[-1,Plus[a,b],x],Hold[Times[Times[-1,Plus[a,b]],x]]]*)
```

Notice that the `Simplify` output has one `Times`, but the input expression has two of them.  That latter behavior is the expected and documented (on [tutorial/OperatorInputForms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html)) behavior.  The way to type in the expression output by `Simplify` is as follows:

```
(-1) (a + b) x === Simplify[-(a + b) x]
(*True*)
```

Why doesn't it format like the LHS on output?  Because nearly everyone would cry bloody murder if `Times[-1,x]` would format as `(-1)x` instead of `-x`.  Is this 100% consistent? No, but it does a pretty good job of approximating how people want to read and right things, and once you know the rules you can be more precise.  (And tweaking these rules can have unobvious but dire consequences, which we know from actual testing.)

Addendum: Note that `(-1)(a+b)` evaluates to `-a-b` since there is a rule to compute the product of any expression with -1.  Hence, the input expression `-(a+b)x` evaluates via `((-1)(a+b))x -> (-a-b)x`.  OTOH, the ternary expression `(-1)(a+b)x` does have a definite rule associated with it, and remains the same when evaluated.

Comment: You are confused about what I am confused about; none of these explanations address my questions. My question has nothing to do with singular cases. And I did realize the distinction between the two `FullForm`s for `-(a+b) x`. Nor do I care about the *formatting* of the output; that's just aesthetic preference. I'm certainly not saying that the output of `Times[-1, x]` should be formatted like `(-1)x`, which would be a disaster for readability. My question is why `Equal` does not always recognize the equality between an expression and the expression that it evaluates to.

Comment: I understand that it can be useful for different expressions to be displayed in the same way, because the gain in readability is worth the slight loss of information. But it seems a little ridiculous to me that merely evaluating an expression can change it so drastically that `Equal` cannot realize that the evaluated expression is equal something which displays as the original expression. I don't think that the evaluation process should change an expression so much that Mathematica itself can no longer keep track of the fact that the evaluated expression is equivalent to the original one.

Comment: @tparker That last thing basically cannot happen.  An evaluated expression is always `Equal` to itself.  And if you accept that different expressions can have the same output formatting--which is the start of your comment--then there will necessarily be expressions which look the same but which are not obviously equal to each other.

Comment: You still aren't understanding my issue. I did not claim that an evaluated expression is not always equal to itself. I claimed that "merely evaluating an expression can change it so drastically that Equal cannot realize that the evaluated expression is equal [to] something which displays as the original expression." I give an explicit example in the OP: `exp = Simplify[-(a + b)x]` returns an expression `exp` which displays as `-(a + b) x`. Then `exp == -(a + b) x` fails to return `True`. This is the behavior I object to.

Comment: It could be avoided if `-(a + b) x` evaluated to either `Times[-1, Plus[a, b], x]` or to `Times[Times[-1, Plus[a, b]], x]`, either of which would be a more natural parsing than the expression that it actually evaluates to, which (as I said) `Equal` is not capable of realizing equals `exp`.

Comment: No, it really couldn't.  You could only reach those states if -(a+b) stayed unevaluated as `Times[-1,a+b]`.  But that would mean that `0-(a+b)` would have to be different from either `-(a+b)` or from `0-a-b`, which would be much, much worse.